# How do I get cURL to work with php 8 on windows 10 pro

Tags: php, apache, curl, php-curl

I am trying to integrate paystack but when i try to start the curl session it keeps giving me that "Fatal error called to undefined function curl.init(()"

I uncommented the "extension = curl" in both the php.ini development and production files and restarted apache which is what i am using to no avail.

Comment: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` are _examples_ for settings to use in either of those two respective environments, but the are normally _not_ the actual ini file used - that is usually `php.ini`. (And when in doubt, call `phpinfo`, it will tell you which configuration file was actually used.)

Comment: As sayd by @CBroe, you first have to check why the curl extension is not loaded (and thys is your curl.init() error). Check you phpinfo() and your log files. Do you run a WAMP btw or an hand-made install?

Comment: I called phpinfo and the tab for loaded configuration file and configuration file path were both none. 
I can’t find any other php.Ini file within the directory which I downloaded. 
Could this be a problem with the installation or what? 

What do you guys best advise please? Do I delete it and download again or there’s a workaround